# Function many to one

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, intuition

Recently I come across this definition of function.
"A function F is a set of ordered pairs $( x , y)$, no two of which have
the same first member. That is, if $(x, y) \in F$ and $(x, z) \in F$, then $y = z$."

It made me confused because as far as i understood that it suggests we can't have one to many function like $\sqrt{x}$. But why this is so?

Comment: Because that's the definition. To clarify: are you asking why mathematicians defined functions this way?

Comment: The example $\sqrt{x}$ may not be a good one, since when we are doing functions of a real variable, $\sqrt{x}$ is the non-negative number whose square is $x$. (In high school they often do things differently.)

Comment: @ Jev, I am asking the same you have interpreted that why have mathematicians defined function that way. Since we have functions in existence that are one to many then don't you think this function definition is not exhaustive.
Thanks,

Comment: Because such things are not functions, but *relations*. So that ground is covered by that more general concept. Also, as mentioned, $\sqrt{x}$ on *reals* is a function, since it by definition refers to the nonnegative square root. In complex analysis, where "multivalued functions" are more often discussed, that term is a *misnomer* that only sticks around by repeated use. The existence of that term does *not* change the actual definition of function.

Comment: All functions are relations, but not all relations are functions. The two-valued square root you mention (which for reals should be denoted $\pm \sqrt{x}$ and not just $\sqrt{x}$ which by definition is the nonnegative square root only, and is a function) is an example of a relation which is not a function.

Comment: More specifically, the two-valued square root and other such "multivalued functions" are more accurately called "left-total" relations.

Comment: You can also interpret such a relation as a true function from its domain to the *power set* of its codomain. But then the output of such a function is not a number, but a set. So care is required.

Comment: Okay Fine,One more thing would anybody like to say anything that why have we defined function in that way only,removing the one to many possibility.

Comment: I was responding to your claim that "there are functions which are one to many", and pointing out this is incorrect, therefore the definition of function is indeed "exhaustive".

Comment: As for why it's defined that way, I'm not sure of the history but I think it comes from the idea of a function as capturing the notion of a quantity which depends upon another. So, a particular quantity, thus one value for the function for a given input.

Comment: For example, the distance covered by a traveler, versus the time elapsed in the trip. There is one distance for each time.

Comment: And in many contexts in math, things just wouldn't work as well if functions were allowed to be multiply-valued. You'd have to add that single-valued qualifier all over the place. Since you'd keep talking about a "single-valued function" all the time, why not just roll that qualifier into the definition of a function and be done with it?

Comment: That is a commonly used definition in introductory texts. For most applications, however, some notions of domain and codomain are required. See Jim's definition, for example. His $X$ is the *domain* of $f$; his $Y$ is the *codomain* of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

A function $f\colon X \to Y$ can be thought of as a subset $F \subseteq X \times Y$ such that

1. For every $x \in X$ there is a $y \in Y$ such that $(x, y) \in F$.
2. If $(x, y), (x, y') \in F$ then $y = y'$.

If you have a function $f\colon X \to Y$ then it corresponds to the ordered pairs $F = \{(x, f(x)) \mid x \in X\}$.  Conversely if you have a set of pairs $F \subseteq X \times Y$ with the above properties then the associated function $f\colon X \to Y$ is defined by letting $f(x)$ be the unique element of $Y$ such that $(x, f(x)) \in F$.

It is indeed true that this means functions cannot be one to many.  In set theory this is part of the definition of a function.  A function $f\colon X \to Y$ is an assignment, to every $x \in X$, of a **unique** element $f(x) \in Y$.

Comment: Here is an alternative formalism that I have found useful:

$f$ is said to be *function* mapping the elements of set $X$ to the elements of set $Y$ iff

$$\forall a\in X: f(a)\in Y$$

Comment: From this formal definition, it follows trivially that $$\forall a\in X:\exists b\in Y : (b=f(a)) $$ and $$\forall a,b\in X :(a=b\implies f(a)=f(b))$$

Answer (score 1):

The notion of function has been so successful in mathematics that it should not be tampered with.

Now it could very well be that in the realm of a certain problem you want to bring in some sort of "many-valued function". You can do this any time by making your "function" set-valued, or even multiset-valued. Then it is again a function in the official sense; but you would have to give explanations what "continuity" and the like would mean in your context.

An example: A polynomial
$$p(z):=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1z+a_0$$
with complex coefficients $a_k$ has $n$ complex roots, counted with multiplicity. These roots depend on the coefficient vector ${\bf a}=(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1})$, but there is no function $$f:\quad{\mathbb C}^n\to{\mathbb C},\qquad {\bf a}\to f({\bf a})$$ producing one or several of these roots upon inputting the coefficient vector ${\bf a}$.

On the other hand you can define the set $M:={\mathbb N}^{\mathbb C}$ of multisets of complex numbers. Each such multiset $S$ is a function $S:\ {\mathbb C}\to{\mathbb N}$ which assigns to each complex number $z$ a certain integer multiplicity. Maybe $M$ is to large for our purpose; therefore we restrict to the set $M_n\subset M$  of multisets of cardinality $n$. Then the fundamental theorem of algebra tells us that there is a bona fide function
$$f:\quad {\mathbb C}^n\to M_n,\qquad {\bf a}\to f({\bf a})$$
producing a well-defined multiset of complex numbers upon inputting a coefficient vector ${\bf a}$. After defining a suitable topology on $M_n$ one can even say that the multiset $f({\bf a})$ depends continuously on ${\bf a}$.